# Retrieve data in html table cell - PHP

Tags: php, html, post, html-table, session-variables

I'm loading data from an xml file into a html table then adding a check box column at the end with the view of saving the data from each row where the check box is checked, for now I just want to display the rows with the check box checked.

In my first page I have the code below which successfully loads the xml data in to the html table and displays it as I wanted, forgive my code, it is a bit messy as I'm new to PHP.

```
<?php
<form method="POST" action="saved.php">
echo "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Save Checked Rows'  />";

$all = simplexml_load_file('list.xml');
echo "<div style='height:200px; overflow-y: scroll;'>";

echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Link</th><th>Save</th>\n";
echo "<tr>";
$c=0;
foreach ($all as $current) {
    $title=$current->title;
    $description=$current->description;
    $link=$current->link;
    echo "<td>{$title}</td><td>{$description}</td><td><a href=$link>$link</a></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='save[]' value='$c' /></td>";
    $c++;
    echo "</tr>\n"; }
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

echo "</form>"
?>
```

On my second page I have the code below which displays the value of every check box that is checked when I submit the first page

```
<?php
Session_start();
?>

<?php
foreach($_POST['save'] as $key){
     echo $key;}
}
?>
```

I need to get the data from the other table cells on the checked rows, the only idea that worked so far was putting an input in to the cell but I don't want that because the cells have to be uneditable. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Use the `readonly` attribute with the input.

Comment: You could get the data from the XML again. This time you don't output but you just check if the $c counter is inside $_POST['save'] - the counter represents the data in your example (with xpath this can even be directly accessed).

Comment: As I'm a bit short of time on this I think I'll display the details in an input but hide it which saves me having to format the css of it, and I'll display it as I am above as well. It isn't the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For that there is an atribute in html which you can use i,e read only

Comment: FOR EXAMPLE if you want to make a textbox noneditalbe                  <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll display the details in an input but hide it instead of making it just read only which saves me having to format the css of it, and I'll display it as I am above as well. It isn't the best solution but it works in getting the details out.